# Specify classes to obfuscate with ProGuard?

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

How do I specify that I want Proguard to obfuscate a set of jar files that I am including in my project?  I have seen the docs:

```
-injars class_path      Specifies the program jars (or wars, ears, zips, or directories).
-outjars class_path     Specifies the name of the output jars (or wars, ears, zips, or directories).
-libraryjars class_path
```

But I still ask which one specifies a jar file to be obfuscated? Not at all clear from the documentation.

I know this is a basic question but lets say I have several jars in libs.jar how to I indicate these as inputs?  Also should it be classpath or can I specify directory.

Comment: Most of the controls are not *per JAR* but rather *per signature* (package, class, etc.). A JAR is just a source (it could just as well be a directory) and does not supply any information for a signature to match AFAIK.

Comment: ok and what might the difference be between an injar and a library jar?

Comment: So what I have is four eclipse project with various dependencies on each other jar files.  One is the executable android project that runs on the device and it include several jar files.  Do I need to tell proguard about these other jars and if so how do I specify them?

Comment: So if I have an eclipse project with included jars a.jar b.jar c.jar do these need to be put in the config file or not?

Comment: Library JARs are not considered for modification by ProGuard (the classes they contain will not be put in "outjars"), but are still needed to resolve referenced types and such. *Only* the classes found in "injars" are considered candidates to "outjars" (after possible ofuscation, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Eclipse and your .jar files are put in `lib/` folder and included in your project, you don't have to worry about them, ProGuard will automatically use them to do its magic.

Comment: ok.  I suppose this is true for ant builds as well as eclipse exports?

Comment: sorry, I don't have experience with ant, I use Eclipse.